# WordPress problem with setting options value for rtl

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, hebrew

I have added php snippet that get terms option and display frontend.
But there is problem after switching to Hebrew.
values are displayed with "-" at the end, instead in front.
I tried almost every css code for unsetting rtl like `direction: ltr !important;`, but unfortunatelly without success.
I will attach two images.
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

```
<div class="elementor-shortcode">
<p>מ <strong class="none-rtl">-0.75</strong> ל <strong>-2.25</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: In order ot perform debugging we need to see your code, not just pictures.

Comment: Yes, just html matters.
I added this clas `none-rtl` for testing purposes.
Problem appears after i switched to Hebrew using WordPress main settings.

Comment: It not clear what you need ... can you reduce the example with just a `<p>מ -0.75 ל -2.25</p>`. I noticed when editing/removing `<strong>` the minus sign jumps to the other side. As Hebrew is RTL I neither understand the `direction: ltr !important;`